# manually entering option fields based on the number of option

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help.I need to enter some elements(words) based on the number of elements.This element number is given as option.for example if the option chosen is 4, 4 empty fields should appear,where the elements to be filled. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all via JavaScript/HTML.

```js
document.getElementById("create").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  
  for (var i = 0, len = document.getElementById('fields').value; i < len; i++) {
    var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.type = "text";
    container.appendChild(inputElement)
  }
});
```

```html
Fields needed: <input type="text" id="fields" value="4" /><br />
<button id="create">create</button>
<div id="container">
  
</div>
```

## If you're interested in jQuery:

```js
$("#create").click(function () {
  $container = $('#container');
  for (var i = 0, len = parseInt($("#fields").val()); i < len; i++) {
    $('<input>')
      .attr('type','text')
      .appendTo($container);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Fields needed: <input type="text" id="fields" value="9" /><br />
<button id="create">create</button>
<div id="container">
  
</div>
```